# MS Access Input Mask Putting an Asterisk on Left and Right

Tags: ms-access, input, field, mask

I'm trying to get an input mask to put an asterisk on the left and right of my value in a field.  I've tried setting up a custom input mask for that field, but `\*CCCCCCCCCC\*;0;` puts it at the beginning, end of the value, and then very end even if I don't have a value whose length extends that far so it ends up looking like `*sample*    *`

I could write a piece of VBA to do this, but I was seeing if I could get help with the input mask first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a variable length input mask.  Your only option is VBA code to create it.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but thanks for the clarification.